# Replace 0 values in list with increment numbers, starting from the highest number in that list

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a list

```
l = [0,1,2,3,4,5,0,23,34,0,45,0,21,58,98,76,68,0]
```

I want to replace all the 0 with an increment value starting from the highest value in the list l. So in this case the highest value is 98 so the 0 should be replace with 99,100,101,102 and 103.

This is my solution and it works fine

```
for ix,i in enumerate(l):
    m = max(l)
    if i == 0:
        l[ix] = (m+1)
```

But I would like to know what is the best way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comphrension, incrementing via `itertools.count()`:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,0,23,34,0,45,0,21,58,98,76,68,0] 
>>> c = count(max(lst)+1)
>>> [x or next(c) for x in lst]
[99, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100, 23, 34, 101, 45, 102, 21, 58, 98, 76, 68, 103]
```